# Is it ok to paste a WordPress Image URL into a post?

Tags: images

I notice that if you insert an image into a post (from your existing media library) WordPress inserts specific WP Code...

My question is (since I am curious) - is there a problem with simply just copying and pasting the image URL and inserting that into the text portion of a (for example) WordPress post?

Thanks

Comment: Problem? No. But you don't get the WP automatic goodies such as alt text, different image sizes properly linked in CSS, expected CSS classes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no actual problem of copying any link to the content. WordPress itself actually has an option for this. If you want to paste a URL, use this feature instead. You can add a media from URL in the `Add media` screen.

Click the `Add media` button in the visual editor, and then choose `Insert from URL` from the left panel. You can then add a caption, alt text and/or align your image.

But if you copy the link directly into the editor, you won't get stuff like captions.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't moving break "regularly" inserted images as well? Unless you are speaking of import/export, a regular copy of files + db will break. (Which is why I'm always `wp search-replace`ing ..)

Comment: @kero This is one the questions I always have in my mind. I never ever had to do any search/replace other than changing the `siteurl` and `homeurl` when I move to another domain. But I notice some people have such problem. This should not be happening, since only the `GUID` column's URLs are hardcoded, and the rest of the images have relative path saved in DB.

Comment: @kero And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwNpc.jpg) is the proof of what I'm talking about. This is from `wp_postmet` table, which shows an attachment's relatively saved URLs. Unless, you mean the images that are directly added to the post itself, which those are hardcoded.

Comment: @JackJohansson After a site migration I **always** use a search and replace plugin to, atleast control my URLs. Maybe there will be no problem with the default image path´s, but for example options or plugins can also save URLs. Just today I moved a website, after migration I searched for the old URL in the database. There were several hundred database cells which had still the old URL. So yeah, I suggest atleast having an eye on the URL´s.